# iPhone 4 (iOS 7.x.x) - Unable to make video calls from any app other than FaceTime

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using iPhone 4 (iOS 7.x.x). I tried doing video call using WhatsApp and few other video calling apps. But it didn't support video call.

Is it a limitation of iPhone 4? Or is there any possibility to resolve the problem?

FaceTime is working but is it available for Android phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although WhatsApp is compatible with iOS 7, the video calling feature requires iOS 8 or later.

FaceTime is available only for Apple's iOS and macOS. You can make a FaceTime call to your contacts using iPhone/iPad (iOS 7 and later) or Mac (OS X 10.9.2 or later). It is not available for other mobile or desktop platforms.

There are various other popular cross platform messaging apps with support for video calling ([Viber](https://itunes.apple.com/app/viber-messenger-text-call/id382617920), [Hangouts](https://itunes.apple.com/app/hangouts/id643496868), [Google Duo](https://itunes.apple.com/app/google-duo-video-calling/id1096918571), [Skype](https://itunes.apple.com/app/skype-for-iphone/id304878510)) but they all require iOS 9 or later to be installed.

You can give [Zoom](https://itunes.apple.com/app/zoom-cloud-meetings/id546505307) a try. It claims to support iOS 7 and later.